# Syntax error, Msg 156, Level 15, and Msg 102, Level 15

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find the city that has got the highest AVG sale.

I built this query but it's not working.

```
SELECT [City] 
FROM Loan
GROUP BY [City]
HAVING AVG(Sale) = (SELECT MAX(AvgSale) 
                    FROM
                        (SELECT AVG(Sale) AS AvgSale
                         FROM Loan
                         GROUP BY [City])
                   );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am thinking:

```
SELECT TOP (1) [City] 
FROM Loan
GROUP BY [City]
ORDER BY AVG(Sale) DESC;
```